# outputting the simplest Backbone view not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm evaluating Backbone for a project and am having a problem getting it to output the simplest view possible based upon binding to an id. Here's the code and I'm sure I'm making a total noob mistake:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='underscore.js'></script>   
<script src='backbone.js'></script> 
<script>

var BandView=Backbone.View.extend({
  el:$('#bands-wrapper'),
  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this,'render');
    console.log('you initialized');
    this.render();
  },
  render:function(){
    console.log('you are about to render');
    this.$el.text('here i am');
    return this;    
  } 
});
var myView=new BandView();
</script>

<body>
before
<div id='bands-wrapper'>
after
```

I'm not getting an error and both error messages are writing to the console. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

thx

Comment: You try to initialize the view before there's `#bands-wrapper` in the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move your code right before closing `</body>` tag. Seems like you are trying to access to the DOM when it is not yet ready.

But the better way is to create separate file, put all logic here and execute it on document.ready.

Comment: ah that did it, the jQuery also worked. Is there any idiomatic way for Backbone? thx for answer

Comment: Backbone doesn't provide an "idiomatic way" to do this. You just have to start your work with the DOM when it is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of your view when the DOM is ready,

```
$(function(){ var myView=new BandView(); });
```